# dividing a string into array after comma c++

Tags: c++11

I have the following string :-

> CoursesExams =
>   HUM001,Technical Writing,28/4/2016,HallA;CSE121,Computer Programming,3/5/2016,HallB]

I want to split it after each `;` into an array.  How can I do that using c++?

Answer (score 1):

Use std::getline and stringstream:

```
std::string s = "HUM001,Technical Writing,28/4/2016,HallA;CSE121,Computer Programming,3/5/2016,HallB]";
std::vector<std::string> arr;
std::istringstream str(s);
std::string elem;

// getline reads str stream until comma is found, then returns string in elem
while(std::getline(str, elem, ',')) arr.push_back(elem);

for (auto& s : arr) std::cout << s << "\n";
```

Comment: the last lint raise the following error: {a function definition isn't allowed here before ':' token }
how can I handle that?

Comment: @HossamSalah do you use c++11 compiler? You can rewrite it as `for (size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {  std::cout << arr[i] << "\n"; } `